# jquery/javascript remove div if jpg not match

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html code:

```
<div class="first div">
    <div class="second">  
        <div class="title">Hi</div>
        <div class="test-icon" style="background-image: url(https://1.jpg);"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="first div">
    <div class="second">  
        <div class="title">Hi</div>
        <div class="test-icon" style="background-image: url(https://12.jpg);"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="first div">
    <div class="second">  
        <div class="title">Hi</div>
        <div class="test-icon" style="background-image: url(https://123.jpg);"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="first div">
    <div class="second">  
        <div class="title">Hi</div>
        <div class="test-icon" style="background-image: url(https://good.jpg);"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to delete all elements with "first div" class if the background image is not: `url(https://good.jpg);`? so the final response will be:

```
<div class="first div">
    <div class="second">  
        <div class="title">Hi</div>
        <div class="test-icon" style="background-image: url(https://good.jpg);"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would be grateful for any assistance, thank you!

Comment: Can we see your Ajax JS? You don't need to "delete" the html, just select the one you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a [WORKING FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gschambial/kb6q13to/8/) of your example:

```
$('.first').find('.test-icon').each(function(){
    if($(this).css('background-image').indexOf("good") == -1){
      $(this).closest('.first').remove();
    }    
});
```

Check [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gschambial/8yt5zm2q/2/) to add multiple images

```
$('.first').find('.test-icon').each(function(){
    if($(this).css('background-image').indexOf("good.jpg") == -1 &&
        $(this).css('background-image').indexOf("good1.jpg") == -1 &&
          $(this).css('background-image').indexOf("good2.jpg") == -1){
      console.log($(this).closest('.first').remove());
    }    
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is really working, thank you so much! It is possible to add multiple good images in this script:

Comment: @AlexandruVorobchevici Glad, i could help. You can mark the answer as done for others' reference.

Comment: how can I add multiple images in this code? like http://good.jpg, http://good1.jpg, thank you again!

Comment: No, I want a white list  for specified images! something like gtrskxd.jpg, mfhdj54.jpg, andsj54k2.jpg

Comment: Then you can simply add `OR` condition in the `if` block

Answer (score 2):

Filter the divs having content with `good.jpg` and remove the negation with `not()` and `remove()`:

```
    $('.first.div').not($('.first.div').filter(
          function(index, element)
          {
               return $(element)
                 .find(".test-icon")
                 .css('background-image').indexOf("good") >= 0
          }
    )).remove();
```

Comment: Why using the `not` function when you can simple switch `>=` with `<` ?

Comment: If it is that simple, post it as answer and get a green tick for the simplest answer

Comment: I was honestly asking if there is a specific reason or not, if not it is indeed redundant. Don't you agree?

Answer (score 1):

```
var first_div = $('div.first.div');

for (var i = 0; i < first_div.length; i++) {
    var background_image = $(first_div[i]).find('.test-icon').css('background-image');

    if (background_image !== 'url(https://good.jpg)') {
        $(first_div[i]).remove();
    }
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: All browsers don't serialize CSS rules the same, e.g, your code will work on Safari, but not on chrome nor FF which will convert it to `'url("https://good.jpg")'`

Comment: @Kaiido Are you sure? How have you checked it? I just test again. It's working good on both Chrome and FF.

Comment: I tested it on chrome 54, FF 50, and safari 9.1.3 all on osx and the results are the ones I gave you. It's probable that results do even differ between different versions of the same browser, and on different platforms.

Answer (score 1):

You need traverse all .text-icon elements with [each function](https://api.jquery.com/each/) of JQuery.

```
$( "div.first .text-icon" ).each(function( ) {
 if( $( this ).css('background-image')!='url(https://good.jpg)' ) {
   $( this ).remove();
 }
});
```

Comment: Even the ones with the correct background-image will be removed here

Answer (score 1):

Working example using `slice` to extract each image url:

```
$('.first').each(function(){
    var img_url = $(this).find('.test-icon').css('background-image').slice(5, -2);
    if (img_url != "https://good.jpg/"){
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this like below:

```
var bg = $('first').find('.text-icon').filter(function(bg) {
    return $(bg).css('background-image') === 'url(https://good.jpg)'; 
    //although you should use '/good.jpg') 
)};
bg.hide();
```

Comment: All browsers don't serialize CSS rules the same, e.g, your code will work on Safari, but not on chrome nor FF which will convert it to `'url("https://good.jpg")'`

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
if ($('.test-icon').attr('background-image') != "https://good.jpg") {
   $('.first div').remove();
}
```

If you want to delete the all "first div" class..

Comment: This removes pretty much everything in the posted HTML fragment. It's typically a good idea to test code before recommending it to others.